# Is multivendor a hard thing to do in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, multistore

My client wants to build a multivendor shop based on magento 2. There's no shortage of extensions that does that, perhaps the most famous is created by webkul, my client was ready to pay webkul a huge sum of money in order to buy many extensions from them.

I wonder if it's a hard task to do by coding because I need the rest api, the extensions don't have a rest API, and at some point in the future, the plan is to create a mobile app.

So if doing multivendor isn't a big deal in magento 2, at least I'd be able to do it the way I want it to be. The less extensions the better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a hard task. A brutal honest assessment. Stick with extension. Plus if things don't go right you've got that additional level of support. Fair enough if their support is bad then you could step in. But generally speaking, it's quicker to fix or adapt than create.

Don't get me wrong I enjoy creating my own extensions as I feel this helps me learn. But I also get frustrated by the length of time it takes me to make changes to certain areas in the checkout for example.

I think it's about recognizing which tasks you could do well in the time constraints that you have and then go from there.

The best example I can think of is that I wrote a PayPal extension for Magento 1. Reason being the client was already using the built-in extension and needed a second account to work alongside existing. I got the job done but it was tedious and no doubt produces the odd exception as I cant code or test to the level of a team of people.